# Foreach giving undefined variable error

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach, undefined

Bare in mind that it's late where I am so this may just be a very simple solution that I am overlooking.

I have this foreach statement:

```
  <? foreach ($entrees as $entree) { ?>
       <li>
           <span class="food-name">
               <?=$entree['name']?>
           </span>
       </li>
  <?}?>
```

That gives an Undefined variable error for $entree.

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

 Severity: Notice

 Message: Undefined variable: entree

 Filename: views/welcome_message.php

 Line Number: 9
```

I tried `print_r($entrees);` and the result was

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Lamb [description] => A small leg of lamb ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Ham [description] => Large thing of ham ) ) 1
```

Again, this may be something stupid simple but I've been trying to 30 min and can't get it to work for the life of me. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You might wanna tag this as PHP as well.

Comment: Yeah, woops. Told you I was tired.

Comment: Usually if `$entree` is undefined then `$entrees` is not an array

Comment: Post the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check to see if the entry name is set in your multidimensional array. Here is the long version because I was unaware of the `short_open_tags` option in PHP.

**Code**

```
<?
$entrees = array();
$entrees[0]['name']="Lamb";
$entrees[0]['description'] ="A small leg of lamb";
$entrees[1]['name']="Ham";
$entrees[1]['description'] ="Large thing of ham";

echo "<ul>\n";
foreach ($entrees as $entree) { 
 if(!empty($entree['name'])){
   echo "<li>";
   echo "<span class=\"food-name\">";
   echo $entree['name'];
   echo "</span>";
   echo "</li>\n";
 }
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

**Output**

```
<ul>
<li><span class="food-name">Lamb</span></li>
<li><span class="food-name">Ham</span></li>
</ul>
```

**Update**
Learned something new thanks to @Arjan - the original code you had with the `[short_open_tags][1]` should also work with the `if` statement provided they are enabled in your build. In my testing they threw an error as my test machine uses an older build of PHP. After rebuilding they do work by default.

```
<?=$entree['name']?>
```

According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) in this usage the `=` sign means `echo()` and is enabled by default in PHP 5.4.1. Upon searching through Google because their searches use the operators differently I was unable to find a link since I did not know the name for the usage. If you're programming with a team of developers make sure to use the same agreed upon tag styles as the rest of the team.

Comment: It sort of works. It repeats the first result. What is this tArr? Can't find it on google.

Comment: It's just a placeholder short for temporary array. We're assigning the key to `$entree` and the value array associated with the `$key` to `$tArr`.

Comment: Eh, I've updated my code. It should be easier for you to follow since it's the style you're used to.

Comment: I was just renaming variables as a test. Copied the wrong error message.

Comment: That works. Some of my accounts are on Dreamhost and they have some strange errors they've compiled in from time to time. "Error: You are not a Jedi." Their server names are strange too... things like `eggnog`.

Comment: When I tried `<? echo $entree['name']; ?>` it showed in DOM as a comment. When I did same thing with `<?php ?>` I got the same undefined variable error.

Comment: I've added an if statement to make sure there is a variable there. If there isn't in your multidimensional array it will throw an undefined index error. The DOM is the Document Object Model. It might have said that if there aren't any <ul> or <ol> tags.

Comment: I am confused by your code though. It's great that is works but I don't understand it. Like the \n and class=\"food-name\">"

Comment: Since I've putting everything into quotes I have to escape the same quotes. The `\n` is a new line character (to make it easier to read in HTML).

Comment: So could the same be accomplished with `class='food-name'` ?

Comment: Yes. As long as the quotes do not match the container they do not need to be escaped.

Comment: Actually, `<?=$foo;?>` is the same as `<?php echo $foo; ?>` if `short_open_tags` are enabled.

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for that. I tried searching for the equal signs but Google returns no results (probably by design). https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=<%3F%3D

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `short_open_tag` to `On` in php.ini. That fixed it for me with no additional code.

Comment: OMG this exact problem has caught me so off guard. Thanks for the tip! (Even if it's been 4 years since you posted it).

To other googlers: an alternative to this solution is to replace actual short open tags (`<?`) with normal ones (`<?php`) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use like ..

```
   <?   
     if(isset($entrees)) {
     foreach ($entrees as $entree) { ?>
   <li>
       <span class="food-name">
           <?=$entree['name']?>
       </span>
   </li>
      <?} } 
       else { echo 'Any thing You want';
      }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
   if(isset($entrees) && $entrees != NULL){
      foreach($entrees as $entree => $arrData){?>
        <li>
          <span class="food-name">
            <?php echo $arrData['name'] ?>
          </span>
        </li>         
     <?}
   }?>
```